# Fonts installed but 'multicols.sty' not found

Tags: texlive

I have both `texlive-fonts-extra` and `texlive-fonts-recommended` installed however I get `'multicols.sty' not found` when compiling a tex file.

How do I fix this?

**Update**: the package is `multicol` without an `s`.

Comment: Are you sure that's not meant to be [multicol.sty](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en)?

Comment: I thought it might be a typo however I copied this [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262716/16946) to double check.

Comment: Actually, you're right however the code still gives a (different) error.  Could you replicate the result if possible?

Comment: What error are you seeing? I took a quick look and it seems like you may need to define `\familyname` and `\firstname` in the preamble (even if empty) as described here [Moderncv - undefined control sequence in minimal document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369382/135380). You may also need to remove the \\ line break after the last `\cventry{}` .

Comment: I updated my answer with @steeldriver 's edits and needed LaTeX packages.

Comment: @steeldriver It was my bad. I had tried compiling it without the basic necessary fields. It works. Thanks

Comment: TBH it really wasn't clear those fields needed to be defined - it's unusual for fragments posted on SE *not* to work out of the box, so I wonder if the package itself has changed (perhaps some default defs were removed)?

Comment: @steeldriver They needed to be defined because it is part of the `moderncv` class. Some fields are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As far I can understand, the file `multicol.sty` [is contained in `texlive-latex-base` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=multicol.sty).

Try to install it with `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base`.

For `ngerman` you should install `texlive-lang-german` with `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german`.

As *steeldriver* recommended, below is working TeX example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\firstname{}
\lastname{}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
    \section{headline}
    \hspace*{\hintscolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0pt}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \cventry{}{C\#}{basic}{}{}{} \par \cventry{}{UNIX}{basic}{}{}{} \par
        \cventry{}{vim}{basic}{}{}{} \par \cventry{}{\LaTeX}{basic}{}{}{} \par
        \cventry{}{HTML, CSS, PHP}{very basic}{}{}{} \par
    \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

It compiles normally from Gummi (`sudo apt-get install gummi`).

All needed TeX dependencies may be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra lmodern texlive-lang-german texlive-latex-base
```